# Open DialogBox in Adapter

Tags: java, android

I want open DialogBox when click on the RecyclerView and this RecyclerView used the custom Adapter. I wrote open DialogBox code in adapter, but when Running Application the error is encountered.

my adapter code :

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter_smiley extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder> {
public String[] mDataset;
static public Context context;


// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley(String[] myDataset) {
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_smiley, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    // - get data from your itemsData at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

    viewHolder.tvtinfo_text.setText(mDataset[position].toString());
    viewHolder.versionName = mDataset[position];
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvtinfo_text;
    public String versionName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        tvtinfo_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardview_title_smiley);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_show__sms__dialog);
                Button close_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_close_button);
                close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });

        itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "test click: " + versionName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

onClickListener code in Adapter :

```
itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_show__sms__dialog);
                Button close_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_close_button);
                close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
```

error :

```
03-09 16:59:53.066    1215-1215/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tellfa.smsbox, PID: 1215
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:156)
        at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:133)
        at com.tellfa.smsbox.CardViewDataAdapter_smiley$ViewHolder$1.onClick(CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.java:73)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the statement on line (CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.java:)73.

Comment: Probably `context` is `null`

Comment: In the above code sent. public void onClick(View v) {
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_show__sms__dialog);
Button close_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_close_button);
close_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
});
dialog.show();
}

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : can you send me true code?

Comment: Looks like its null whenever you are trying to dismiss it  try    if(dialog!=null) {dialog.dismiss();}

Comment: @Xjasz, please send me this code :(

Comment: check out the answer just put your dialog.show() in that if statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                    int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        context = parent.getContext();
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.cardview_smiley, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Comment: tnx, but show error in running application! Do you know how to fix null of context ?

Comment: sorry I see the real issue now copy my answer.  Your context is null that will set your context to whatever the parent is

Comment: No, the adapter is completely separate from the activity. Please see the code to understand of my mean

Comment: Well how can I fix this problem?

Comment: replace your CardViewDataAdapter_smiley method with my answer and it should work.

Comment: You're wonderful, it's ok. tnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnx my dear friend <3